# python sql ORDER date doesn't work

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite, sql-order-by

I ran into another (probably self inflicted) issue.
Python3.6 and sqlite
I'm very sufficient in creating a db and adding tables and info and all that. My issue is, that the info I'm ading is not sequential. But I'd like it to be sorted inside the db, so it's easier to process. Below is my code that is supposed to Sort (ORDER) my table entries by the Timestamp named "datum". If I run the same query from within sqliteman on ubuntu it works and reorders the lines as I want it to. However if I try it in python it doesn't work?

```
con = lite.connect(db_name)

with con:
    try:
        cur = con.cursor()

        strExec = "SELECT * FROM " + db_table_name + " ORDER BY datum ASC"
        cur.execute(strExec)
        con.commit()
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
cur.close()
con.close()
```

Here are the entries for datum in that table. There are hundreds of entries, but I'm only showing a few here.

```
2017-12-23T00:00:00
2017-12-25T00:00:00
2017-12-24T00:00:00
2017-12-21T00:00:00
2017-12-24T00:00:00
2017-12-26T00:00:00
2017-12-12T00:00:00
```

Any idea what I'm missing here?
Thanks!

```
# ============================
# EDIT
# ============================
```

As answered below, the order in which data resides inside the db's tables is completely irrelevant. The data needs to be ordered and put in whatever sequence is needed when working with the data only. Therefore the code snippet below is one example to get that data into the desired order.

```
db_result = cur.fetchall() 
for row in db_result:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Can you expand on what "it doesn't work" means? Looking at the code I don't see anything trying to read the results from the query out - so it seems the code sample may be incomplete. From what I recall of the DB2.0 API in python, you'd want: `cur.execute(query); cur.fetchall()` ([fetchall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall)). [Even better would be just iterating the rows in the cursor]

Comment: Are you under the impression that executing that query will somehow automagically reorder your database table itself?

Comment: What do you expect `cur.execute` followed by `con.commit` to accomplish exactly? `commit` only works if you're modifying the DB, and a `SELECT` does not modify anything. Your question really doesn't make a lot of sense as written when you look at the code you're using. A `SELECT` retrieves data, and you have to read the rows it returns.

Comment: That is where my problem lies. I tried a fetachall() and printed them out on the screen. Everything was in order, so I guess I have to write them back then, as the query only sorts them and "pushes" them in order to me for display. That makes sense. So how do I write them back into the db? Create new table, delete old one and then rename the new to the old name? Or is there an easier way? Please explain!

Comment: No point in trying to write them back in some order.

Comment: Datasets are inherently unordered. The ONLY way to get results in a specific order is with `ORDER BY`. Trying to order the data while it is still in a table is pointless.

Comment: Some DBs do btw [offer tools for handling the physical order](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-cluster.html), but their use case is not ordering query results.

Comment: Oh ok, so if I understand right, I should just not care about the order in which my entries are in that table, but rather sort them by timestamp when working with the data, is that correct?
I didn't know, as I have not much experience with db's.
OK Thanks everyone then! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL tables are unordered.

If you want to retrieve rows from a table in a specific order, you have to add an ORDER BY clause to every query that retrieves rows.

Comment: That's what I did initially, I was just unaware that the order in the db's table is irrelevant and I need to order the results when fetching data from the db to work with. See my corrected question above